# Mounting ISO in Linux/KDE

Tags: mount, kde, iso, dolphin

Is there a graphical, preferably integrated with Dolphin, utility for mounting ISO images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best answer to your problem is to add contextual menus for Mount/Unmount in Dolphin, or service menus as they are called in KDE.

To do this, you need to:

1. create the folder where the ISO will be mounted. (for this example I will use /mnt/iso)
2. navigate to `/usr/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus`
3. create a new file with `.desktop` extension (I used iso.desktop)
4. add the following lines:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Service
   ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
   MimeType=application/octet-stream;
   Actions=mountISO;umountISO;

   [Desktop Action mountISO]
   Name=Mount
   Icon=utilities-terminal
   Exec=kdesu 'sudo mount -o loop,ro -t iso9660 "%f" /mnt/iso/'

   [Desktop Action umountISO]
   Name=Unmount
   Icon=utilities-terminal
   Exec=kdesu 'sudo umount "%f"'
   ```
5. If kdesudo is available on you system instead of kdesu, then add the following lines instead:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Service
   ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
   MimeType=application/octet-stream;
   Actions=mountISO;umountISO;

   [Desktop Action mountISO]
   Name=Mount
   Icon=utilities-terminal
   Exec=kdesudo 'mount -o loop,ro -t iso9660 "%f" /mnt/iso/'

   [Desktop Action umountISO]
   Name=Unmount
   Icon=utilities-terminal
   Exec=kdesudo 'umount "%f"'
   ```

OBSERVATIONS:

- mounting to /media/iso instead of /mnt/iso will cause the mounted iso to conveniently appear as a read-only drive in Dolphin places.
- in the `ServiceMenus` directory you can find other examples of how the file should be formatted.
- the syntax is pretty so i will not describe it (please comment if you have questions).
- this method works for only one ISO at a time, as they are all mounted in the same directory and I could not yet find a way to overcome this.
- you will be prompted for password each time you mount/unmount
- in the end it should look like this:
  [image: problem solved!]

[Here](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Simple+mount+Iso+service+menu?content=148881) is an app that does all of the above.

Comment: Please don't post just a link. Your post should make sense even if the reader does not choose to follow the link. See [how to answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: There's kdesudo ...

Comment: This actually made Dolphin crash every time I right-clicked on something. Then I downloaded a service menu that provides a similar script and menus, and now everything works butter smooth. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this hits anyone else, but in Plasma5/KF5, the directory is `$KF5/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus`, and at least for my `kdesu` installation, I needed to prepend the commands with `-c`, eg `Exec=kdesu -c 'sudo mount .....'`

Comment: this doesn't work anymore in Plasma 5.8

Comment: Could not make it work in KDE Neon 18.04

Answer (score 2):

Simple service menu based on [KDE-Services](https://store.kde.org/p/998464) and [Mount ISO image](https://store.kde.org/p/1201701/) (more details [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1005285/47206)):

```
 kate ~/bin/iso_manager-mount-image.sh
```

With this content (pasting this here in order to avoid the need of installing KDE-Services or uploading the script):

```
#!/bin/bash

#################################################################
# For KDE-Services. 2012-2017.                  #
# By Geovani Barzaga Rodriguez <igeo.cu@gmail.com>      #
# Improved by Victor Guardiola (vguardiola) Jan 5 2014      #
#   -Fixed the problem of [dir|file]name with whitespaces.  #
#################################################################

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/$USER/bin
MOUNTEXIT=""

##############################
############ Main ############
##############################

cd "${1%/*}"

if [ "$1" == "${1%.*}.iso" ]; then
   fuseiso -p "$1" "${1%.iso}"
   MOUNTEXIT=$?
else
   rename .ISO .iso *
   kdialog --icon=ks-error --title="Mount ISO-9660 Image" \
                   --passivepopup="[Error] Can't mount ${1##*/}: Renamed extension of ISO image, because contain uppercase characters. Please try again."
   exit 1
fi

if [ "$MOUNTEXIT" = "0" ]; then
   kdialog --icon=ks-media-optical-mount --title="Mount ISO-9660 Image" --passivepopup="[Finished] ${1##*/} mounted."
else
   kdialog --icon=ks-error --title="Mount ISO-9660 Image" \
                   --passivepopup="[Error] Can't mount ${1##*/}: Already mount or check image integrity."
   exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Then:

```
kate ~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/mount-iso.desktop
```

with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=application/x-cd-image;model/x.stl-binary
Actions=mount;unmount;
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel
X-KDE-StartupNotify=false
Icon=application-x-cd-image
X-KDE-Submenu=Mount/unmount image


[Desktop Action unmount]
Name=Unmount
Icon=edit-redo
Exec=which fuser fusermount; if [ "$?" != "0" ];then kdialog --icon=ks-error --title="Unmount ISO-9660 Image" --passivepopup="[Error] Please install fuser and fusermount command and try again."; exit 1; else fuser -k %f; fusermount -u "$(ls "%f"|sed 's/.iso$//')"; rm -fr "$(ls "%f"|sed 's/.iso$//')"; kdialog --icon=ks-media-optical-umount --title="Unmount ISO-9660 Image" --passivepopup="[Finished] $(basename %f) unmounted.";fi

[Desktop Action mount]
Name=Mount
Icon=circular-arrow-shape
Exec=which fuseiso; if [ "$?" != "0" ];then kdialog --icon=ks-error --title="Mount ISO-9660 Image" --passivepopup="[Error] Please install fuseiso command and try again."; exit 1; else ~/bin/iso_manager-mount-image.sh %F;fi
```

[image]

It will mount the image in a newly created folder inside the same directory as the image, and that folder will be deleted when the unmount option is selected for the iso.

`fuser`, `fusermount`, `fuseiso` and `kdialog` are needed."

---

**Acetoneiso** comes in Plasma 5 with only three supplementary packages: `fuseiso` and other two that are `qt`-based.

```
sudo apt install acetoneiso
```

To see it in Dolphin you have to add the program to the file properties of the iso file.

[image]

Then, it can be found in Dolphin under the *Open with* option:

[image]

That will mount the image, open it in Dolphin, and also open the Acetineiso window, where you can find the **Unmount** option.

[image]

---

There is also `gnome-disk-utility` which, in spite of the name, comes without non-kde dependencies in Plasma 5.8 (in fact no dependencies at all), and it includes (beside `gnome-disks`, also called "Disks", default in Ubuntu) a tool called `gnome-disk-image-mounter`.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

After that, a Dolphin context menu entry is created, accessible by selecting 'Open with' - 'Disk Image mounter'.

[image]

---

These programs could be used with a service menu also (but they both lack an unmount command).

For example, one could use this with Acetoneiso:

```
kate ~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/acetoneiso-mount-iso.desktop
```

with the content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=application/x-cd-image
Actions=mount
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel
X-KDE-StartupNotify=false
Icon=application-x-cd-image
X-KDE-Menu=Mount with Acetoneiso



[Desktop Action mount]
Name=Mount with Acetoneiso
Icon=Acetino2
Exec=acetoneiso %f
```

[image]

---

There seem to be a sort of bug here when using this programs with Dolphin: unmounting  from the Acetoneiso button or from the Dolphin devices list, the list entry will remain there (called 'Loop device' in the case of `gnome-disks`) which, if selected, will again mount the image. That entry will stay there until system restart (logout is not enough). (The first script is not affected by this.)

Comment: This is probably the simplest, sanest option for most users.

Comment: @iLikeDirt - I have updated the answer to give multiple solutions, including a simplified script that I prefer.

Comment: https://www.opendesktop.org/p/1214091/

Comment: I have noticed that in Ubuntu 18.04, in order for a Dolphin context service menu to work for iso files, the desktop file needs `model/x.stl-binary` for the `Mimetype` line.

Comment: AcetoneISO (like FuriusISOMount) does not adapt file permissions when mounting. So I can't install run script (e.g. for installing software) from the mounted ISO. Any solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

In a number of distros there exists a separate [Dolphin Plugins package](https://apps.kde.org/dolphin_plugins/) that includes disk mounting (such as ISOs). It's typically named [`dolphin-plugins`](https://pkgs.org/download/dolphin-plugins) across distros.

If Dolphin isn't presenting the option in the context menu check if the plugins are installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try either `acetoneiso` or `EasyISO`

acetoneiso can be found in Ubuntu.

And source code of EasyISO [was here](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=148840)

[image]

Just drag the image in, and double to open the mounted folder.

Answer (score 0):

Marius Cotofana provided a great answer, but here are two additional notes:

1. When kdesu is not available in your KDE configuration (if the
   kdesu command doesn't work in bash/konsole), use kdesudo to create
   the mount/unmount context menus in Dolphin.
2. Creating /media/iso and mounting the image to that will cause the image to show up in places under Dolphin as read only which provides additional conveniences.

> [Desktop Entry]
>   Type=Service
>   ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
>   MimeType=application/octet-stream; Actions=mountISO;umountISO;
>
> [Desktop Action mountISO]
>   Name=Mount
>   Icon=utilities-terminal
>   Exec=kdesudo 'mount -o loop,ro -t iso9660 "%f" /media/iso/'
>
> [Desktop Action umountISO]
>   Name=Unmount
>   Icon=utilities-terminal
>   Exec=kdesudo 'umount "%f"'

Answer (score 0):

Combining all the above answers, this works perfect for me on Kubuntu 19.10 in 2020. No `kdesu` or `kdesudo` needed. Only downside is it doesn't report errors, it fails silently.

```
kate .local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/iso_mounter.desktop
```

And add this config:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=application/x-cd-image;application/octet-stream;
Actions=mount;umount;
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel
X-KDE-StartupNotify=false
Icon=media-import-audio-cd
X-KDE-Submenu=Mount/Unmount Image

[Desktop Action mount]
Name=Mount
Icon=media-import-audio-cd
Exec=pkexec 'env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY mount -o loop,ro -t iso9660 "%f" /media/iso/'

[Desktop Action umount]
Name=Unmount
Icon=media-eject
Exec=pkexec 'env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY umount "%f"'
```

Answer (score -2):

what is "Linux"??

In my Ubuntu 12.04, you only need:

1. search .iso file
2. right click over
3. Select the first option: "Open with Archive mounter"

Then a CD icon appears on net group of the file browser.
That's all!

Comment: You are likely using GNOME/Unity + Nautilus. My question is about KDE + Dolphin.

Comment: Fwiw, I am using Linux Mint 13, KDE edition.