# Is there a KDE tool for mounting disk images, like GNOME Disks?

Tags: mount, kde, iso, plasma5

I am not aware of a KDE-native tool to mount iso images in Plasma 5 and I keep using the Gnome tool `gnome-disk-utility`, as indicated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/319018/32012).

Is there a KDE version of this tool? It is able to do more than just add a context menu entry to mount iso files, like setting mounting options and backing up partitions, but I am mostly interested in the 'mount iso' option.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If what is wanted is a separate Qt-based gui,  **Acetoneiso** qualifies: it is written in Qt and can mount and unmount images; it installs `fuseiso` and two `qt` packages.

But in spite of its name `gnome-disk-utility` only comes by itself with no packages foreign to KDE. It includes the `gnome-disk-image-mounter` tool which does the actual job.

To install:

```
sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility
```

To run "Disks":

```
gnome-disks
```

To mount an image file:

```
gnome-disk-image-mounter
```

or execute the file `/usr/share/applications/gnome-disk-image-mounter.desktop`. This executable is not found by the launcher as long as it contains the line `NoDisplay=true`; change that to `false` to launch it as any other program.

(then select the iso)

To add it to context menu:

```
kate ~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/mount_gnomedisks.desktop
```

(be sure you have the folder `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus`)

then paste these lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]

Actions=mount
Icon=dialog-information
MimeType=application/x-cd-image;application/x-raw-disk-image;model/x.stl-binary
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Type=Service
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel


[Desktop Action mount]
Exec=gnome-disk-image-mounter %U
Icon=drive-removable-media
Name=Mount image
```

and save.

---

And there are also the Dolphin services; most of those do not work, as they are outdated, and the newest ones are not the best rated. Luckily, there are exceptions, like **KDE-Services** (https://store.kde.org/p/998464). It seem it cannot be installed from the Dolphin-Services button; instead, it can be downloaded as tar.bz2 archive, unpacked and, by opening a terminal in the resulting folder, it can be installed by running the command `sudo make install`. This is a collection of services, desktop files installed at system level in `/usr/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/` and scripts installed in `usr/share/applications`.

To have a simplified service menu based on this, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/319018/32012) answer.

Answer (score 6):

There should be an Dolphin (KDE's default filemanager) plug-in.

Dolphin: Control -> Configure Dolphin... -> Services -> Download New Services... -> Search for 'mount'

---

UPDATE:

What works in 2018 with Plasma 5.8 is [KDE Services](https://store.kde.org/p/998464).

[image]

There is also the possibility of modifying such scripts - for example this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47080/mounting-iso-in-linux-kde/319018#319018).

[image]

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/115781/gui-tool-to-extract-iso-file-contents-on-linux-kde

Comment: I have updated the above answer with a service that works.

Comment: there is another small dolphin service called "Mount ISO image here or elsewhere" ... i just installed and it works

Answer (score 2):

This is a built-in feature of Dolphin as of [version 20.08](https://kde.org/announcements/releases/2020-08-apps-update/).

When you right-click an iso file it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the native application KDE Partition Manager. Visit https://apps.kde.org/en/partitionmanager

You can set up the device, mount point and many other options, such as Read-only, No automatic mount, Synchronous access, No binary execution, Users can mount and umount, No update of file access times, No update of directory access times, Update access times relative to modification, UID, GID and access umask. Very complete tool.